# How to read CSV file with newline and comma characters inside cells in C++

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I've got a CSV file containing cells with break lines ("\n") and/or commas which are enclosed with double quotes. 
When I use getline() function to get each row, it consider each line inside cell as a new row of csv file. In addition, when using splitIntoVec to get vector of each row, it condiders comma inside a cell as a new vector element.
I want to store the content of csv file into a vector of vectors which each row is a vector of strings inside its cells.

for instance, for the following csv file content

```
"Row 1 cell 1
 With break line","Row1 cell2, with comma"
"Row 2 cell 1
 With break line","Row2 cell2, with comma"
 Row 3 cell 1,Row3 cell 2
```

I get the result vector of 4 string vectors which the first one has only one element and the second one has 3 elements. 
Here is my code :

```
vector<vector<string>> readFromCsv(string &fileName, char rowDelimiter = "\n", char colDelimiter = ",") {
    ifstream file(fileName); // declare file stream
    string value;
    vector<vector<string>> contentVec;
    vector<string> rowVec;
    string rowStr;
    while (getline(file, rowStr, rowDelimiter)) {
        rowVec = splitIntoVec(rowStr, colDelimiter);
        contentVec.push_back(rowVec);
    }

    return contentVec;
}
```

Is there any other function (in libraries like boost) available to resolve these issues? Any help would be appreciated.

**In PHP , I get the content of the csv file by fgetcsv() correctly . Is there any alternative function in c++?**

Comment: What you are trying to parse is not a CSV. CSV syntax is defined by [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) and the first point of the document states: `Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line break (CRLF).`

Comment: What about double quote inside a cell?

Comment: @SimoneCifani the csv file I use is created by PHP. Besides, I've created the comma-delimited csv file by excel and Libreoffice and still seen the same result.

Comment: @DAle yep! :|.  The cell might contain double quote. But I've ignored this case to avoid more complexity !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Simone already said in his comment that it is not the CSV file. But seeing your problem you will need to get your hand dirty and do some text processing to get it separate. You can read complete file in a string and then break it further using loops or which ever way you see fit. For this you will need to keep track of the encountered " while traversing and breaking only when it is not inside double quotes.

For Example,

(opening apostrophes)"Row 1 cell 1
 With break line"(closing apostrophes),"(opening apostrophes)Row1 cell2, with comma"(closing apostrophes)

You will have to keep track of opening and closing double apostrophes using index or number and break for rows only if '\n' is found outside the opening and closing apostrophes.

You can use regex also if you are sure there are no " in the cells.

Thanks @Alex Useful link if someone else faces the same issue : http://mybyteofcode.blogspot.nl/2010/11/parse-csv-file-with-embedded-new-lines.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Yes I think I have to do the parsing myself in the end :/ !  Considering the generality of the problem, do you know any function in libraries like Boost to do the trick? Because every comma-separated csv file that is created by editors has this kind of format.

Comment: You can write this function once and use it when required for parsing ;) I am not sure if boost has any such sort of function though. And if it doesn't have you can contribute there if you can make it generic.

Comment: Read this. This should help.
Link: http://mybyteofcode.blogspot.in/2010/02/parse-csv-file-with-boost-tokenizer-in.html

Comment: @Aref You can decide how to tokenize using boost. I didn't know about it before but its possible.

Comment: thanks very much , it worked :). I got it working by modifying the following link from the same website : http://mybyteofcode.blogspot.nl/2010/11/parse-csv-file-with-embedded-new-lines.html .

Comment: Mark the answer accepted that will help me getting some reputation if you like :P

Comment: please add the above link in your post so I can accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to completely separate by `"`, keeping 2 states: inside `""` and outside.  `,` and `EOL` have different meanings based on the states.

You can use `getline(file, rowStr, '"')` to read in everything up to the `"`, but your logic to separate in records will be a bit more complex.  If numbers are allowed without quotation marks, then it becomes even more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the problem is that when a cell doesn't contain special characters like "\n" and "," , it's not enclosed with double quote (") .  How can I deal with this situation? In PHP , I correctly get the content of the csv file by fgetcsv(). I wonder why there is no alternative in c++ !